# using mingw on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, make, configure, mingw

I need to build Windows binaries from a conventional source tarball.  I recall that I used to do this in a RedHat environment using specialised configure and make scripts from mingw packages.  But I'm now on Linux Mint and have no idea.  What packages do I need?  What do I use to configure and make?  The source files are in C and gcc is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need C, install `gcc-mingw-w64`:

```
sudo apt install gcc-mingw-w64
```

This will install the full toolchain, allowing you to build 32- and 64-bit Windows binaries using either POSIX or Win32 threads; you can install more specific packages if you’re interested in a subset of that only.

Once you have the compiler, configure your build using

```
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32
```

for 32-bit programs, and

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

for 64-bit programs.

Comment: Thanks.  Supplementary question: is there a comparable set of tools for cross-compiling to MacOs binaries?

Comment: I’m not aware of any.